# Check if ALL conditions specified are satisfied in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets assume I have the following derived table:

```
Comment | Condition_Lower_Score | Condition_Higher_Score | Question_Score
=========================================================================
text1   |          1            |            3           |       2
text1   |          3            |            5           |       4
text2   |          5            |            6           |       1
text2   |          3            |            6           |       4
```

My table has a comment which is in a one to many relationship with conditions. Each condition can specify multiple questions(in this table the question score relates to different questions). I need to create a query that only selects the comment if all its conditions are satisfied.

The derived table is created from the following tables:

Comment:

```
Comment_ID | Comment_Text 
===========================
     1     |     text1
     2     |     text2
```

Condition:

```
 Condition_ID | Condition_Lower_Score | Condition_Higher_Score |  Comment_ID | Question_ID
 =========================================================================================
      10      |          1            |             3          |      1      |     100
      11      |          3            |             5          |      1      |     101
      12      |          5            |             6          |      2      |     102
      13      |          3            |             6          |      2      |     103
```

Question:

```
Question_ID | Question_Score
============================
     100    |       2
     101    |       4
     102    |       1
     103    |       4
```

So in this scenario, I would like only 'text1' to be selected from the derived table, and not 'text2' because all its conditions are not satisfied.

How do I create a query that only selects if all the conditions are met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH TestsCTE AS
(
SELECT M.Comment_Text AS Comment, 
       C.Condition_Lower_Score, 
       C.Condition_Higher_Score, 
       Q.Question_Score,
       CASE 
           WHEN Q.Question_Score BETWEEN C.Condition_Lower_Score AND C.Condition_Higher_Score
           THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS Pass
FROM   [Condition] C
       JOIN Comment M
           ON C.Comment_ID = M.Comment_ID
       JOIN Question Q
           ON C.Question_ID = Q.Question_ID
)
SELECT COMMENT
FROM TestsCTE
GROUP BY COMMENT
HAVING MIN(Pass) = 1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/821f78/3)**

Comment: But where is this checking that all conditions are met for 'text1'?

Comment: What are the conditions? The JOIN statements should handle that. Based on your sample tables my query should return the first two rows of your expected results.

Comment: The Condition_Lower_Score and Condition_Higher_Score. See how question scores for 'text1' fall inside the range of the two score thresholds.

Comment: Ok... now i got your question... Let me revise

Comment: Giannis - thanks for the revision, but this will select if any condition is met. I'm editing the question slightly - where the comment should be selected only if all conditions are met. see now text2 should not be selected

Comment: Would you like to know only the comment? or do you want all the other values too?

Comment: Just the comment is fine

Comment: Thank you Giannis, I am unfamiliar with creating a looping case statement in sql. Thank you for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
select comment from (
    <query for your derived table here>
) t1 group by comment
having count(
   case 
   when question_score not between condition_lower_score and condition_higher_score 
   then 1 end
) = 0
```

or

```
select c.comment_text from comment c
join condition co on co.comment_id = c.comment_id
join question q on q.question_id = co.question_id
group by c.comment_text
having count(
   case 
   when question_score not between condition_lower_score and condition_higher_score 
   then 1 end
) = 0
```